# is there a way to to do the following

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, use-effect, use-state

[image]
is there a way I can empty the input field and still return to default "technology" results on the page[image]

By default data showing are correct, it fetches data as I type(due to dependency) is also working fine but as soon as i empty input..[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the error by adding a check before the `article.map` block is rendered:

```
<div className="wrapper">
    { article ? (article.map(...)) : 'No article found...'}
</div>
```

If you need to reset the `input` state to `Technology` you can define a custom function, and call it when needed:

```
const resetInput = () => {
    setInput('Technology')
}
```